# Covering of the plane by the grid squares

Tags: plane-geometry, probabilistic-method

Consider the covering of the plane by the grid squares, that is, by the unit squares whose vertices are the grid points.

Prove that there is an absolute constant $C > 0$ so that for every $0.1 > ε > 0$
there is a set $F$ of points in the plane containing exactly one point in each grid square so that every planar (not necessarily aligned) rectangle of dimensions $\epsilon \times C \frac 1 \epsilon \log(\frac 1 \epsilon)  $, contains at least one point of $F$.

Comment: I don't know, but $\epsilon$-nets might be relevant.

Comment: This article seems very relevant. http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/forest1.pdf

Comment: To be clear: the dimensions of the arbitrarily aligned rectangles we care about are $\epsilon \times C \log(1/\epsilon) \frac 1 \epsilon$ ? 

See [Minkowski's convex body theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem), which seems very relevant.

Comment: Dear @ArtimisFowl, I do not grasp a strong connection between the problem and Minkowski's theorem. Can you please elaborate on what you have in mind?

Comment: @Pachirisu It's not as strong as I'd hoped. Minkowski would give an easy proof, or counterexample, for F a shifted lattice. Unfortunately, I see now that this case is already trivial. My apologies.

Comment: Why not taking F as the central points of every rectangle do not work as set?